# What does this iptables entry mean?

Tags: iptables

iptables-save output:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [2929:172650]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [74596344:6265371965]
```

These are the opening lines of the iptables-save command. What do the numbers in the square brackets mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the packet counter and byte counter that you can get live with the `iptables -L -v` command.

Examples and explanations can be found in the [Iptables Tutorial - `iptables-save`](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/iptables-save.html) document.

Comment: Man that was silly of me, thanks for the prompt response. I was searching t'interwebs for the answer but I couldn't find the answer, although I wasn't too sure what search phrase to use. Many thanks Mat.